# Whats wrong with this step / method?

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

For the feature

```
Feature: One      
  Scenario Outline: Validate 
    Given ["<a>"|"<b>"|"<c>"|"<d>"|"<e>"|"<f>"|"<g>"|"<h>"|"<i>"|"<j>"|"<k>"|"<l>"]

  Examples:
    | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k | l |
    ....
```

Auto generated step is

```
@Given("^\\[\"(.*?)\"|\"(.*?)\"|\"(.*?)\"|\"(.*?)\"|\"(.*?)\"|\"(.*?)\"|\"(.*?)\"|\"(.*?)\"|\"(.*?)\"|\"(.*?)\"|\"(.*?)\"|\"(.*?)\"\\]$")
public void (String arg1, String arg2, String arg3, String arg4, String arg5, String arg6, String arg7, String arg8, String arg9, String arg10, String arg11, String arg12) throws Throwable {
 ...          
}
```

but this method is not recognized. In IntelliJ, error `Variable 'String' is already defined in scope` for args (2,4,6,8,10 and 12) is thrown. Even `spaces` in method definiton (e.g. space between `void and (` throws `identifier expected`.  Whats wrong with this method?.

Comment: Side note: I don't know cucumber jvm, but the string looks like a regex to me: If it is a regex, note that the pipe symbol (`|`) is reserved and needs to be escaped. `\\|`

Comment: Guys, I don't mind a down vote but it helps if it is explained.

Comment: @BackSlash: You are right.  Got it sorted. You could post it as an answer.

Comment: It seems to be missing method name